# C# WEB (RESTful)API 4.5 Routing the proper/smartest way for Oauth2.0

Tags: c#, api, asp.net-web-api, routes, oauth-2.0

I am developping a RESTful WEB API using asp.net web API. When i came to implement the Oauth2.0 service i found a small routing problem.

Example:

I have 3 controllers:

```
public class A_Controller : ApiController
{

    public string get()
    {
        return "call A controller";
    }
 }
```

---

```
public class B_Controller : ApiController
{

    public string get()
    {
        return "call B controller";
    }
 }
```

---

```
 public class C_Controller : ApiController
{

    public string get()
    {
        return "cal lC controller";
    }
 }
```

All off them return some information.

**What i want to do is:**

For default call:

```
.../api/{Controller}
```

Proceed with **basic authentication**.

For this call:

```
.../api/oauth/{Controller}
```

Proceed with my **Oauth implementation**.

This have to work for all Controllers.

What i tried:

```
       config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "OauthApi",
            routeTemplate: "api/oauth/{Controller}",
            defaults: new
            {
                token_num = RouteParameter.Optional,
                action = "Oauth"
            }
        );

        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "DefaultApi",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}",
            defaults: new
            {
                action = "Default"
            }
        );


public class A_Controller : ApiController
{
    [ActionName("Default")]
    public string get()
    {
        return "call withouth Oauth";
    }


    [ActionName("OauthAction")]
    public string getOauth()
    {
        //do some Oauth check
        return "Oauth with token in header!!!!";
    }
```

---

Comment: `/api/oauth/{Controller}` is not equal to the maproute `api/oauth/token/{token_num}/{Controller}`?

Comment: it is, but thats not the point... sorry going to edit now

Comment: @ErikPhilips it was copy-paste problem :)

Comment: Your question is really ambiguous.  Do you need help with design, routing, security, or ...?

Comment: @ErikPhilips design of routing, you see, i want to be able to call my controllers withouth Oauth and with oauth when it comes in url

Comment: What is the difference between the two methods besides authorization?

Comment: None, it is just a way to provide different ways of authorization. I have 7 Controllers and i want them all to support "Oauth prefix"

Answer (score 1):

Here is what I would do, assuming the user is *already authorized*.

Create your routes:

```
config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
  name: "OauthApi",
  routeTemplate: "api/oauth/{Controller}/{Action}",
  defaults: new
  {
    action = "Default"
  }
); 

// or if you have the token in the path..

config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
  name: "OauthApi",
  routeTemplate: "api/oauth/{OAuthToken}/{Controller}/{Action}",
  defaults: new
  {
    action = "Default"
  }
); // This is really just for URL match, as the Token shouldn't be used
   // by the controller or action

config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
  name: "DefaultApi",
  routeTemplate: "api/{Controller}/{Action}",
  defaults: new
  {
    action = "Default"
  }
);
```

Controllers:

```
public class A_Controller : ApiController
{
  [ActionName("Default")]
  [CustomAuthorize()]
  public string get()
  {
    return "Requested Data";
  }
}
```

Custom Authorization

```
public CustomAuthorizeAttribute : AuthorizeAttribute
{
  protected override bool AuthorizeCore(HttpContextBase httpContext)
  {
    // do OAuth checking
    if (HttpContext.Current.Request.Path 
    or HttpContext.Current.Request.QueryString["OAuthToken"].Equals())
    {
      return true;
    }

    return base.AuthorizeCore(httpContext);
  }
}
```

Now your controllers do only [what they are suppose to, return data](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle).  And you have a reusable way to authorize all requests.

[If you are using MVC 3 or higher, you could just global authorize everything with OAuth](http://weblogs.asp.net/jgalloway/archive/2012/04/18/asp-net-mvc-authentication-global-authentication-and-allow-anonymous.aspx).

```
public static void RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilterCollection filters)
{
  filters.Add(new CustomAuthorizeAttribute());
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much, i will give it a read and a try tomorrow.Although it look a little confusing.

Comment: We can certainly chat about it if you'd like.

Comment: What do you mean by "assuming the user is already authorized"? The goal of having "../oauth/.." before "../{controller}/.." is to decide what type of Authentication to use.

Comment: I'm assuming that if OAuth is in the url, then they have an OAuth token (they have Authenticated).  What I've written is how to Authorize (what the user has access too).  None of this has anything to do with Authentication (who the user is).